# How to derive this formula if the assumptions are true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let ($x,y$) and $r$ are a point in a Cartesian coordinate system and a distance from the origin to that point, respectively. Obviously, we have these relations
$$
\begin{align}
x &= r\cos\theta \\
y &= r\sin\theta \\
r^2 &= x^2 + y^2
\end{align}
$$
Are the following relations true, if yes, why?

$$
\begin{align}
x = \frac{1}{2}x\cos(\theta/2) + \frac{1}{2}y\sin(\theta/2) \\
y = \frac{1}{2}x\cos(\theta/2) + \frac{1}{2}y\sin(\theta/2) \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Don't think you meant the last two relations to be identical $\,x \equiv y\,$. Anyway, try a few simple cases and see what happens, for example $\,\theta=0\,$.

Comment: Yup. That's what I did. Wonder what was really meant - this is obviously a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $t$ for
$\theta$,

$\begin{align}
x = \frac{1}{2}x\cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2}y\sin(t/2) \\
y = \frac{1}{2}x\cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2}y\sin(t/2) \\
\end{align}
$

$\begin{align}
x &= r\cos t \\
y &= r\sin t \\
r^2 &= x^2 + y^2
\end{align}
$

If $t=0$
then
$x=r, y=0$,
this is

$\begin{align}
r = \frac{1}{2}r \\
0 = \frac{1}{2}r \\
\end{align}
$

which is false.